# Time Optimization For Feed API (Inside A List Of different API calls)

Tags: java, multithreading, http, data-structures, completable-future

There is a REST API for a Dashboard Feed Page. The is containing different Activities with pagination. The Different APIS are getting data from different Database collection as well as Some Http 3rd party API's.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(params...) {
List<Map<String, Object>> uhfList = null;
        Map<String, Object> uhf = null;
           for (MasterModel masterModel : pageActivities) {    //Taking Time n (which I need to reduce)
                uhf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                uhf.put("Key", getItemsByMethodName(params..));
                uhfList.add(uhf);
            }
return uhfList;
}



  private List<? extends Object> getItemsByMethodName(params...) {
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = null;
        List<? extends Object> data = null;
        try {
            method = uhfRelativeService.getClass().getMethod(params...);
            data = (List<? extends Object>) method.invoke(params...);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error Occure in get Items By Method Name :: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I tried It with different approach by using Complatable Future But not much effective !

```
private CompletableFuture<List<? extends Object>> getItemsByMethodName(UserDetail userIdentity, UHFMaster uhfMaster) {
    java.lang.reflect.Method method = null;
    CompletableFuture<List<? extends Object>> data = null;
    try {
        method = uhfRelativeService.getClass().getMethod(uhfMaster.getMethodName().trim(),params...);
        data = (CompletableFuture<List<? extends Object>>) method.invoke(uhfRelativeService, userIdentity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error  :: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return data;
}
```

//MasterModel Class

```
public class MasterModel {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String param;
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private Integer param3;
    private Integer param4;
    private Integer param5;
    private Integer param6;
    private Integer param7;
    private Integer param8;
    private Integer param9;
    private String param10;
    private String param11;

//getter & setter
}
```

But the time is not much reduced. I need a solution to perform this operation fast with less response time. Please Help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multithreading, then just casting to a `CompletetableFuture` won't help. To actually run a process asynchronously in a separate thread, you can do something like:

```java
public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(params...) {    
    UHFMaster master = null;             // assume present
    List<UserDetail> userDetails = null; // assume list present

    // just an example
    // asynchronous threads
    List<CompletableFuture<List<? extends Object>>> futures = 
        userDetails.stream().map(u -> getItemsByMethodName(u, master));
    
    // single future which completes when all the threads/futures in list complete
    CompletableFuture<List<? extends Object>> singleFuture = 
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);

    // .get() on future will block - meaning waiting for the completion
    List<Map<String, Object>> listToReturn = 
        singleFuture.get().map(i -> new HashMap() {{ put("Key", i); }});

    return listToReturn;
}

private CompletableFuture<List<? extends Object>> getItemsByMethodName(UserDetail userIdentity, UHFMaster uhfMaster) {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = uhfRelativeService.getClass().getMethod(uhfMaster.getMethodName().trim(),params...);

        return CompletableFuture
            .suppyAsync(() -> method.invoke(uhfRelativeService, userIdentity));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error  :: ", e.getMessage());
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```